# How do I activate button if at least one checkbox is selected? - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an alert dialog that displays a series of check boxes.
I am trying to ensure that if at least one of the checkboxes is selected, the confirm button is enabled, otherwise, if no checkbox is selected, it appears as inactive.

I have a parent and a child widget, both statefull. In one of them I have the button that should be enabled / disabled, and in the other one I have the content of the alert dialog.

The challenge for me has been to notify the parent widget from the child widget, that the flag variable with which I determine whether the button should be active or not, has been updated.

I have tried sending a function to the child widget that it executes, also with ValueSetter and ValueChanged, but so far without success.

If after activating or inactivating one of the checkboxes, I do a hot reload, the button is also updated. So I think it may be something with setState that I am not taking into account.

This is what I have done so far, ready to copy and paste into dartPad.

Thanks for your help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: FrequencySelectionPage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FrequencySelectionPage extends StatefulWidget {
  FrequencySelectionPage();

  @override
  _FrequencySelectionPageState createState() => _FrequencySelectionPageState();
}

class _FrequencySelectionPageState extends State<FrequencySelectionPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                  title: Text('Some days of the week'),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right_rounded),
                  onTap: () {
                      _showDialog(context);
                  }
                ),),
    );
  }

  void _showDialog(BuildContext context) {
    final double screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    bool? canConfirm;

    void setCanConfirm(bool value) {
      setState(() {
        canConfirm = value;
      });
    }

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Choose days"),
          content: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: screenSize * 0.60,
            child: ShowAlertContent(
                setCanConfirm: setCanConfirm),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
                width: screenSize * 0.50,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: Text('Cancel'),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        child: Text('Confirm'),
                        onPressed: (canConfirm == false)
                            ? null
                            : () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class ShowAlertContent extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueSetter<bool> setCanConfirm;
  const ShowAlertContent(
      {required this.setCanConfirm});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return ShowSomeWeekDaysOptionContent(setCanConfirm: setCanConfirm);
  }
}

class ShowSomeWeekDaysOptionContent extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueChanged<bool> setCanConfirm;
  const ShowSomeWeekDaysOptionContent({required this.setCanConfirm});

  @override
  _ShowSomeWeekDaysOptionContentState createState() =>
      _ShowSomeWeekDaysOptionContentState();
}

class _ShowSomeWeekDaysOptionContentState
    extends State<ShowSomeWeekDaysOptionContent> {
  Map<String, bool> days = {
    'Day1': false,
    'Day2': false,
    'Day3': false,
    'Day4': false,
    'Day5': false,
    'Day6': false,
    'Day7': false
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            children: days.keys.map(
              (day) {
                return StatefulBuilder(builder:
                    (BuildContext context, StateSetter setCheckboxState) {
                  return CheckboxListTile(
                    title: Text(day),
                    value: days[day],
                    onChanged: (bool? value) {
                      setState(() {});
                      setCheckboxState(() {
                        days[day] = value!;
                        if (days.containsValue(true)) {
                          widget.setCanConfirm(true);
                        } else {
                          widget.setCanConfirm(false);
                        }
                      });
                    },
                  );
                });
              },
            ).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you need something which rebuilds the button, when the value of `canConfirm` changes. You could use a `ValueListenableBuilder`. Therefore you have to make canConfirm a `ValueNotifier`.

Here is the working example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: FrequencySelectionPage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FrequencySelectionPage extends StatefulWidget {
  FrequencySelectionPage();

  @override
  _FrequencySelectionPageState createState() => _FrequencySelectionPageState();
}

class _FrequencySelectionPageState extends State<FrequencySelectionPage> {
  late ValueNotifier<bool> canConfirm;

  @override
  void initState() {
    canConfirm = ValueNotifier(false);
    super.initState();
  }

  void setCanConfirm(bool value) {
    canConfirm.value = value;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
            title: Text('Some days of the week'),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right_rounded),
            onTap: () {
              _showDialog(context);
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showDialog(BuildContext context) {
    final double screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Choose days"),
          content: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: screenSize * 0.60,
            child: ShowAlertContent(setCanConfirm: setCanConfirm),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: screenSize * 0.50,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: Text('Cancel'),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                    width: 20.0,
                  ),
                  ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
                    valueListenable: canConfirm,
                    builder: (context, value, child) {
                      return ElevatedButton(
                        child: Text('Confirm'),
                        onPressed: (value == false)
                            ? null
                            : () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class ShowAlertContent extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueSetter<bool> setCanConfirm;

  const ShowAlertContent({required this.setCanConfirm});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShowSomeWeekDaysOptionContent(setCanConfirm: setCanConfirm);
  }
}

class ShowSomeWeekDaysOptionContent extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueChanged<bool> setCanConfirm;

  const ShowSomeWeekDaysOptionContent({required this.setCanConfirm});

  @override
  _ShowSomeWeekDaysOptionContentState createState() =>
      _ShowSomeWeekDaysOptionContentState();
}

class _ShowSomeWeekDaysOptionContentState
    extends State<ShowSomeWeekDaysOptionContent> {
  Map<String, bool> days = {
    'Day1': false,
    'Day2': false,
    'Day3': false,
    'Day4': false,
    'Day5': false,
    'Day6': false,
    'Day7': false
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            children: days.keys.map(
              (day) {
                return StatefulBuilder(builder:
                    (BuildContext context, StateSetter setCheckboxState) {
                  return CheckboxListTile(
                    title: Text(day),
                    value: days[day],
                    onChanged: (bool? value) {
                      setCheckboxState(() {
                        days[day] = value!;
                        if (days.containsValue(true)) {
                          widget.setCanConfirm(true);
                        } else {
                          widget.setCanConfirm(false);
                        }
                      });
                    },
                  );
                });
              },
            ).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It makes a lot of sense that the button needs to be rebuilt. I'm going to read more about ValueListenableBuilder and ValueNotifier. Thank you very much Tim.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know about your case but ummmm..  I think this one maybe a lot easier

```
`bool _isChecked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Checkbox(
          value: _isChecked,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _isChecked = value;
            });
          },
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Button'),
          onPressed: (){
            if(_isChecked){
              print('CHeckbox is checked');
            }else{
              print('CHeckbox is not checked');
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }`
```